# Android Studio: How to close a dialog fragment from a recyclerview(adapter.java) hosted in a fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, adapter, dialogfragment

I have a dialog fragment in a recyclerview which works fine. The problem is i am not able to close it after the user has selected one of the options from the dialog fragment (The dialog fragment has another recyclerview populating it on whose item click i want to do something and close the dialog fragment). There are partial answers around but nothing complete.

Thanks
For overview
Fragment>RecyclerView>Dialog Fragment>RecyclerView with menu options

On click of menu options i want to close the dialog fragment.

Following is the adapter code where from i call the click event on the view:

```
public class ContextMenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContextMenuAdapter.contextMenuViewHolder> {

ArrayList<ContextMenuModel> contextMenuList;
Context contextMenuContext;

public ContextMenuAdapter(ArrayList<ContextMenuModel> contextMenuList, Context contextMenuContext) {
    this.contextMenuList = contextMenuList;
    this.contextMenuContext = contextMenuContext;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public contextMenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View contextMenuView = LayoutInflater.from(contextMenuContext).inflate(R.layout.sample_context_menu_rv, parent, false);
    return new contextMenuViewHolder(contextMenuView);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final contextMenuViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ContextMenuModel accountFeedModelPosition = contextMenuList.get(position);
    holder.tvContextMenuOption.setText(accountFeedModelPosition.getMenuOption());

    // On Click Listener for the recycler view items.
    // 1. On Click menu option
    holder.tvContextMenuOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(contextMenuContext, "Clicked"+ holder.tvContextMenuOption.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contextMenuList.size();
}

public class contextMenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView tvContextMenuOption;

    public contextMenuViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvContextMenuOption = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvContextMenuOption);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally achieved it by following this post:
[How to dismiss a dialog fragment from a recyclerview adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316131/how-to-dismiss-a-dialog-fragment-from-a-recyclerview-adapter)

**Solution:**

1. In the adapter.java add to the adapter a constructor that receive DialogFragment.

   ArrayList contextMenuList;
   Context contextMenuContext;
   DialogFragment cmDialogFrag; //For this purpose

   public ContextMenuAdapter(ArrayList contextMenuList ,
   Context contextMenuContext, DialogFragment cmDialogFrag) {
   this.contextMenuList = contextMenuList;
   this.contextMenuContext = contextMenuContext;
   this.cmDialogFrag = cmDialogFrag; //For this purpose
   }
2. When you create the Adapter in the activity.java or fragment.java pass value for constructor created in step 1, like this:

   ContextMenuAdapter myCMAdapter = new ContextMenuAdapter(contextMenuList , 
   getActivity() , ContextMenuFragment.this);

Here the last one i.e. ContextMenuFragment.this will be passed to the constructor created in step 1.

3. Inside the onClick of recyclerview view call:

   cmDialogFrag.dismiss();

Answer (score 1):

if you have a reference to the dialog fragment, you can do this by using `dismiss()` directly on the DialogFragment.

from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#dismiss()) :

`public void dismiss ()`  :

Dismiss the fragment and its dialog. If the fragment was added to the back stack, all back stack state up to and including this entry will be popped. Otherwise, a new transaction will be committed to remove the fragment.

Comment: How do i get a reference to the dialog fragment, please?

Comment: Fragment f=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_layout_id);